# How do you answer a question when asked what is the granularity of the data you worked on?

Tags: database, database-design, data-modeling, data-warehouse

I have been asked the above question but i know only its meaning that its the finest level of data. for example, if you have name in fact table, then its detail such email, phone number,etc can be found in dimensions table. I have sample dataset and its area level analysis which i have worked on, Please explain granularity of data based upon this data.

**Dataset:**

| itemid | item | RID | Rname | Area | Time_Availability>70% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6222589 | peanut banana | 1000 | Cafe adda | gachibowli | True |
| 6355784 | chocolate fudge | 2000 | Santosh hotel | Attapur | False |

***Area level of analysis of restaurant on boarding to a platform***

| Area | Total Ingested restaurants | Available | items_Available >=5 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Gachibowli | 5 | 4 | 2 |
| Attapur | 5 | 4 | 2 |

**Thank you**

Comment: From a [website](https://c3.ai/glossary/features/data-granularity/): Data granularity is a measure of the level of detail in a data structure. In time-series data, for example, the granularity of measurement might be based on intervals of years, months, weeks, days, or hours. For ordering transactions, granularity might be at the purchase order level, or line item level, or detailed configuration level for customized parts. The name field could represent the full name or have separate entries for first name, middle name, and last name.

Comment: "granularity" doesn't mean anything in particular. It is a metaphor. Who asked you? What meaning did the person who asked you mean? How is it defined & used in whatever reference/context you share with them? What did your research there show? [ask] [Help]

Comment: In your first table, you have time availability > 70%.  Where are your detailed time availability tables that demonstrate that chocolate fudge was only available 59% of the time the restaurant was open the last month?  That's granularity.

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc Whatever you're trying to define "granularity" as in that last comment (or the previous one), you aren't succeeding.

Comment: Interview panel asked first what is granularity of data you worked (i was not knowing anything about this term), then after asking clarification he asked what was granular column? Finally when he didnt get proper answer he asked which is theprimary key in your data? @philipxy

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The granularity of a fact table is the minimum set of attributes that will uniquely identify a measure.

For example (and I'm not saying this is a real world example), if you had a sales fact table and there could only be one sale per customer per day then "per customer per day" would be the granularity of that fact table. You might have other dimensions such as the store that the sale occurred in or the country where the transaction took place - but these would not affect the granularity if you could still only have one sale per customer per day, regardless of which store or country that transaction took place in